# element.getAttribute("value") reurn java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.5" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(

Tags: java, selenium

If anyone can look at a problem I have in selenium.
I try to access the result in the above calculator with:

```
public String getAttributeValue(WebElement element) {
    return element.getAttribute("value");
}
```

When the result is a complete integer (such as 1, 2, etc.) the method succeeds, but when the result is with point (such as 0.5) I get this error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.5"  at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

I probably have to change the way I look, or I miss something.
I'd love to help thank you.

[See the dom picture here !!!!! :-)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugpDa.png)

Comment: Did you look at the entire stack trace of the exception?  It contains the line number in your code where the exception occurred.  And it didn’t happen in `getAttributeValue`.

Comment: Accept the answer which correctly solves your problem by clicking on tick icon corresponding to it

Answer (score 0):

As your number can contain decimal values, you can handle it by returning the float value after getting the value by using `getAttribute` method.
You can do it like:

```
public Float getAttributeValue(WebElement element) {
    return Float.parseFloat(element.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to convert the value to string and return.

```
public String getAttributeValue(WebElement element) {
    return String.valueof(element.getAttribute("value"));
}
```